# Reporting in TestNG(index.html)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Can i display at runtime the parameters passed from a method(with test) to another method(which has test) in TestNG Report

Note:
Dataprovider should'nt be used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have unnecessarily limited yourself by not allowing DataProviders.

However, you can extend TestNG so that it intercepts a test and then produces a log entry or other recording. You pass in a class that acts a test listener to TestNG.

```
java org.testng.TestNG -listener com.example.MyTestListener testng.xml
```

Your test listener extends the `TestListenerAdapter` class, which implements the `ITestListener` interface.

```
public class MyTestListener extends TestListenerAdapater {
  @Override
  public void onTestStart(ITestResult context) {
    // context holds the method, parameters and other information used in the test
    ...
  }
  // other phases can be checked
}
```